# Total voltage doesn't add up to 5V

Tags: arduino, voltage

I made a simple LED circuit with an Arduino Uno with a 220 ohm resistor.

I measured the voltage across the outputs on the wires.

It shows 5.08V.

When I measure the voltage across the LED and the resistor separately I get 1.740V and 3.020V respectively.  That makes 4.760V in total.

Why is it not 5.08V? Does that indicate internal resistance of the breadboard?

---

Thanks a lot for your thorough explanations. @hacktastical I actually had a constant high drive and your explanation makes sense, thank you.

I have one more question though; why do I then get 5.08V across outputs of the Arduino without any circuit in between? I mean if the internal resistance of the components cause this, shouldn't I still measure less than 5V in this circumstance?

Comment: At least *some* of the missing voltage is inside the UNO, dropped across the MOSfet logic switch.

Comment: Start at a terminal on the power supply, and then walk your meter around a circuit to the other terminal of the power supply.  It should add up.

Comment: Everything had resistance,but you forgot 1, the driver

Comment: Beware of cheapo breadboards. They can have significant contact resistance.

Answer (score 4):

tl; dr: There will be some IR drop in the UNO (ATMega328) I/O driver. Your measurements didn't account for that.

**Why the IR Drop At The Pad?**

The ATMega328 pads have a P/N pair of MOSFETs. These have an 'on' resistance Rds(on) that will insert its own IR drop when presented with a load. This would add to the total IR drop.

How much is the Rds(on)? They don't say directly. We can nevertheless figure this out from the datasheet specs for high and low drive:

- High: V(oh) @ 20mA = 4.2V, IR drop is 0.8, **worst-case p-FET Rds(on) is 40 ohms.**
- Low: V(ol) @ 20mA = 0.9V, IR drop is 0.9, **worst-case n-FET Rds(on) is 45 ohms.**

(Datasheet link [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf))

These values would be for a worst-case part at high temperature. A typical part at room temp will have Rds(on) at half of worst case, about **20-25 ohms**.

**Accounting For the IR Drop**

We know from the 220 ohm resistor IR drop that the pad is sourcing or sinking **13.7mA**. We also know the 0.320V measurement discrepancy you're seeing is due to the pad's IR drop due to Rds(on), which we can compute as follows:

- Rds(on) = 0.320V/13.7mA = **23.4 ohms**

Very reasonable for this part, right in the middle of typical range.

Adding all the IR drops together:

- 1.74V (LED forward voltage)
- 3.02V (220 ohm resistor)
- **0.32V (Pad IR drop due to Rds(on), 23.4 ohms)**
- sum is **5.08V total**

Comment: I actually had a constant high drive and your explanation makes sense, thank you.

I have one more question though; why do I then get 5.08V across outputs of the Arduino without any circuit in between? I mean if the internal resistance of the components cause this, shouldn't I still measure less than 5V in this circumstance?

Comment: The voltmeter has very high impedance. So if there’s nothing else on the drive-high pad, you will see the supply voltage. The pad in high state looks like a 23 ohm resistor to Vcc.

Comment: By pad you mean Arduino right? If yes, I am talking about the outputs on Arduino, that's where I measure 5.08V. But when I connect an LED and a resistor across those outputs the sum doesn't add up to that voltage.

Comment: Yes, pad=the Arduino (ATMega328) I/O pin. With the LED connected, measure from Vcc to the pad, it will be 0.32V. That’s the internal resistance IR drop.

Answer (score 3):

The missing voltage is due to the \$V_{OL}\$ or "output voltage when signaling logic low", internal to the ATmega328's GPIO output pin. When GPIO is driving a logic 0, it does not go all the way to 0 volts. It gets close enough to be a digital 0. The actual voltage will vary depending on the load current, temperature, and manufacturing variances. However there is a maximum (upper limit) given in the ATmega328 datasheet: \$V_{OL}\$ maximum of 0.9V when sinking 20mA. Remember that's a maximum, it can be lower than 0.9V and still be a good device. In your example it seems under your test conditions, \$V_{OL}\$ is observed to be about 0.3V, which is indeed < 0.9V.

[image: ATmega328 datasheet DC characteristics - VOH]

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are entirely correct, but let me try a simpler approach. I assume your circuit looks like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frMO9l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, you've measured the voltage across the resistor and the LED, and they don't add up to 5.08 volts.

Fine.

Now go back and do it again. This time, also measure the voltage from the bottom of the LED to ground. See if that doesn't make more sense.

Comment: It is actually I believe 12V (from laptop) coming into Arduino or I connect a 9V battery to it. But I measure 5.08V across the output and ground cables. However when I connect the LED and the resistor in series I don't get that total voltage. I tried to measure the voltage from the bottom of the LED to ground but I don't see any voltage there.